# Module not found: Can't resolve './aws-exports'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, node-modules, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Trying to create a react-native app using expo and AWS Amplify. I just went through all of the basic initialization steps of getting the app hosted on Amplify's admin console and then getting a basic GraphQL schema set up, [as per Amplify's Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js/). Upon trying to launch my app with `expo start` I get the following error in `App.js`:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './aws-exports'
  16 | import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
> 17 | import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
  18 | Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

Notably, if I comment out lines 16-18 and try running `expo-start` again, the app runs just fine (just without the AWS-backend being plugged in)

Anyways, when I first saw this, I went and reviewed the import statements and found that while there was a module for `aws-amplify`, there wasn't one that existed in my repository for `aws-exports`. So I tried a few commands to see if I could get it downloaded.

1. `npm install aws-amplify` to try and get the node module installed again
2. `amplify init` to re-initialize the backend
3. Re-cloning the github repo and trying `amplify pull` to grab the existing backend I'd previously created and try it on a new instance of the application.

I haven't had much luck with any of these attempts so I'm hoping to find more help here! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have the `aws-exports` file in that directory? It is supposed to contain the config required by `aws-amplify`. The docs you linked clearly mentions it

Comment: For me aws-exports exists, but it is ignored in git source control.

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with there not being properly integrated CI/CD between your front and back end. Here is [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-config-autogeneration.html) on how you can easily set this up.

*Please don't remove aws-exports from your gitignore, it can contain secrets that sould not be exposed*

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have already run the command `amplify init` in the terminal to initialize your amplify application and that your aws-exports file exists in the same directory as your app.js is?

If yes, then you need to understand that the aws-exports is an autogenerated file created when you initialize or pull the backend environment. The file by default exports an object named awsmobile. To make sure that it does, open the aws-exports file and check the name of the default export, copy that and replace the awsconfig in your `import 'awsconfig' from './aws-exports';` statement.

Comment: I somehow missed the fact that aws-exports is an autogenerated `.js` file and not another node module! I wasn't sure why it wasn't finding it based on the `./` path so I went ahead and replaced the line with the full path which seems to have resolved the problem!

Comment: @CarsenMiller, Glad you were able to resolve it. Hope you don't mind upvoting my answer. :)

Comment: this isn't very clear you commentary azher

Comment: @AllisLove Anything specific you want me to clear about this? :)

Comment: To clarify (maybe for AllisLove), look at your App.js file. After you ran `amplify init` AWS will put the line "import awsExports from './src/aws-exports';" in your App.js (or App.jsx) file. However, it will only create an aws-exports.js file in the root folder and add it to the .gitignore file. Change the source of the aws-exports file in App.js and comment out the line for aws-exports in your .gitignore file. I hoep that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `aws-exports` from `.gitignore` this solves my issue.

Comment: This works, but does it have implication? why is it gitignore? I assume u shoulnt upload this file to amplify.
After the error is gone, I suggest consider adding it again to gitignore

Comment: why would it be in gitignore in the first place?

Comment: @LautaroJorgeGarcia Because [Amplify ignores it by default](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files/#gitignore).

Comment: In a section called "#amplify-do-not-edit-begin"
it seems like you need to reconsider this advice??? Or at least qualify it with more detail.

Comment: This should not be voted up, as sensitive information may be contained in aws-exports.js

Comment: I pushed the "aws-exports.js" file and it fixed the issue I was facing on Amplify. I recommend manually adding and bypassing the ".gitignore" only once because it is only needed once (at least for me). However please use caution if you are worried about the "sensitive information" that Adam Ryason mentioned.

Comment: Voting down for being a personal hack and not a solution to the underlying issue